# Using conditionals, I'm getting different results depending on whether I use SUM or not

Tags: mysql

I have a query that adds up the total value of an order (sum of quantity*price for each product). I want to have a column that contains the total value of only "A" size products. So it should sum up quantity*price for all products except for the "C" size product.

As long as I return a row for each product, I get the expected results: $5 for each A size product and $0 for the C size product (in the smallsize column).

```
SELECT
part_num, email, b.item, b.size_code,
IF(b.size_code IN ('A','B'), quan * price,0) AS smallsize,
quan * price AS price
FROM `orders` AS b
INNER JOIN `groups` AS a
  ON b.ordnum = a.line_num
INNER JOIN `prices` AS c
  ON c.item = b.item AND c.size_code = b.size_code

| part_num |        email | item | size_code | smallsize | price |
|----------|--------------|------|-----------|-----------|-------|
|        2 | me@email.com | 7400 |         A |         5 |     5 |
|        2 | me@email.com | 7400 |         C |         0 |    20 |
|        2 | me@email.com | 7790 |         A |         5 |     5 |
|        2 | me@email.com | 7870 |         A |         5 |     5 |
|        2 | me@email.com | 7910 |         A |         5 |     5 |
```

But when I try to sum up the prices, the C size product is included in the total ($5 + $5 + $5 + $5 + $20 = $40).

```
SELECT
part_num, email,
IF(b.size_code IN ('A','B'), sum(quan * price),0) AS smallsize,
sum(quan * price) AS price
FROM `orders` AS b
INNER JOIN `groups` AS a
  ON b.ordnum = a.line_num
INNER JOIN `prices` AS c
  ON c.item = b.item AND c.size_code = b.size_code;

| part_num |        email | smallsize | price |
|----------|--------------|-----------|-------|
|        2 | me@email.com |        40 |    40 |
```

Why does the first query return a total of $20 (if you add up the smallsize column) and the second query return $40 for smallsize?

I've created a sqlfiddle to illustrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ccd8/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `IF` expression inside the `SUM`. Otherwise you're summing up **all** the rows, and then the `IF` is deciding whether to show the sum or `0` in the final result (which is indeterminate, it depends on which row's `b.size` it happens to choose).

```
SELECT
part_num, email,
    sum(IF(b.size_code IN ('A','B'), quan * price,0)) AS smallsize,
    sum(quan * price) AS price
FROM `orders` AS b
INNER JOIN `groups` AS a
  ON b.ordnum = a.line_num
INNER JOIN `prices` AS c
  ON c.item = b.item AND c.size_code = b.size_code;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5ccd8/5)